# Doctrine persist:

Tags: mysql, symfony, addition

I'm a beginner at Symfony. My problem is that I try to add values to my base MySQL and the problem is that I have the same id, but i verified my entity and i generate values `@ORM/GeneratedValues`, i don't understand where is my fault.

Routing :

```
esprit_parc_AjoutVoiture:
    path:     /Ajout_voiture/
    defaults: { _controller: ParcBundle:Voiture:add }
```

My controller:

```
public function addAction (Request $Request)
{
    $Voiture = new Voiture();

    $form = $this->createForm(VoitureType::class,$Voiture);
    $form->handleRequest($Request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($Voiture);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
            'esprit_parc_Affichage'
        ));
    }

    return $this->render(
        'ParcBundle:Voiture:ajout.html.twig',
        array('form'=>$form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

Entity *Voiture*:

```
<?php

namespace ParcBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
* Class voiture
* @package ParcBundle\Entity
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="Voiture")
*/

class Voiture
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column( type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
     *
     */
    private $Serie;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime",length=255)
     */
    private $DateMiseCirculation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
     */
    private $Marque;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ParcBundle\Entity\Modele" )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id");
     */
    private $modele;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getModele()
    {
        return $this->modele;
    }

    public function setModele($modele)
    {
        $this->modele = $modele;
    }

    public function getSerie()
    {
        return $this->Serie;
    }

    public function setSerie($Serie)
    {
        $this->Serie = $Serie;
    }

    public function getDateMiseCirculation()
    {
        return $this->DateMiseCirculation;
    }

    public function setDateMiseCirculation($DateMiseCirculation)
    {
        $this->DateMiseCirculation = $DateMiseCirculation;
    }

    public function getMarque()
    {
        return $this->Marque;
    }

    public function setMarque($Marque)
    {
        $this->Marque = $Marque;
    }
}
```

Error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Voiture (serie, date_mise_circulation, marque, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2313", "2012-12-03 02:02:00", "sd", 1]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

PS : i have values with `id = "1"` and it should increment automatically the id.

[EDIT]: Class `VoitureType`:

```
<?php

namespace ParcBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class VoitureType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Serie')
            ->add('DateMiseCirculation')
            ->add('Marque')
            ->add('modele', EntityType::class, array(
                "class" => "ParcBundle:Modele",
                "choice_label"=> "libelle"
            ))
            ->add("Ajouter",SubmitType::class);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ParcBundle\Entity\Voiture'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'parcbundle_voiture';
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `VoitureType`, do you have field `id`?

Comment: i generated with the command i will paste it here 1 min

Comment: it suppose an automatic generate i think i don't need to put it in voitureType

Comment: Do you have current schema in database? Maybe your field `id` has not `primary key` in SQL schema? Try to run `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                            
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE modele CHANGE id id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL':                 
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'FK_265FB893BF3967  
  50' of table 'parc.voiture'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an old schema in your database and *MySQL* does not know that attribute `id` is auto increment value. To update your schema you can use one of methods:

1. Internal tool from Doctrine: `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`.
2. Use [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html).

Remember that sometimes schema do not want to update because of foreign keys. Solution for this is just remove existing data.